# How to pass implicit parameter to implicit class

Tags: scala, design-patterns, implicit

I want to pass implicit parameter to my pimped type as I am doing in the actual type. But since implicit classes take only a single parameter, I don't have a way to implicitly pass the parameter to my new type.

```
package com.abc.xyz

class Pet(val petName: String){
  override def toString = petName
}

class PetLover(val name: String)(implicit val pet: Pet) {
  def showLove = s"${name} shows love, ${pet} waves tail"
}
```

I am trying to pimp PetLover into PetTrainer and add a new method train:

```
package com.abc

import com.abc.xyz.PetLover

package object mno {
  implicit class PetTrainer(val trainer: PetLover) extends AnyVal{
    def train = s"${trainer.name} show hand," //${pet} high fives"
  }
}
```

What can I do to make Pet available implicitly to the PetTrainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is already available through `trainer.pet`:

```
def train = s"${trainer.name} shows hand, ${trainer.pet} high fives"
```

If this weren't the case, you could add an implicit parameter to `train`:

```
def train(implicit pet: Pet) = s"${trainer.name} shows hand, ${pet} high fives"
```